# Converting HTML to PDF with images for a secure site

Tags: pdf-generation

Below is the HTML that I want to convert to a PDF.

```
    Hi Hello how are you?        
   <p><img height="151" width="154" src="http://qa.openoffice.org/branding/images/bannerlogo.png" alt=""></p>

   <p><img height="151" width="154" src="https://www.nprocure.com/nprocure_images/banner.jpg" alt=""></p>
```

I tried JODConverter, iText and some tools in the market to do so.
But the image for which the source is https doesnt get converted. The rest of the HTML does get converted.

Any clues on how we can embed the secure images in PDF?
I am looking for some java code snippets to do so.

Regards,
Tina Agrawal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The www.nprocure.com security certificate is not trusted. That could be the reason why the image is not converted.

Check out the Pdfcrowd HTML to PDF API for java: http://pdfcrowd.com/web-html-to-pdf-java/

You can test your HTML code online at pdfcrowd.com/#convert_by_input. The created PDF looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is the http client underneath the pdf libraries that you are using.

I would start off by abstracting the html resolution into it's own piece with something stand alone such as the [apache http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html). Once you get that going, you can hopefully plug in what you get from it into a PDF renderer and hopefully get what you need.

Good luck!